# Word for "the process of becoming a taboo"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would be roughly equivalent to "the process of becoming a taboo," specifically in the context of film/literary criticism, where the "taboomanization" of sexuality serves as a common literary theme in the type of fiction I'm writing about.

Comment: Related (but not a dupe): [What is the historic process for converting vulgar words into simply rude words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17773/what-is-the-historic-process-for-converting-vulgar-words-into-simply-rude-words)

Answer (score 4):

*tabooization* is used:

[image: tabooization]

Here is a random example from *[The International Politics of Sport in the Twentieth Century](http://books.google.com/books?id=_tqmbuzin08C&pg=PA203&dq=%22tabooization%22&hl=en&ei=0RyvTYbBJ4y10QGktYSxCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22tabooization%22&f=false)* By James Riordan, Arnd Krüger:

> Along with it arose a strong 'tabooization' of sexual themes generally known as Victorianism.

Answer (score 2):

Probably "demonization" is the closest we've got. When Captain Cook brought the word "tabu" back from Polynesia, it caught on quickly in English because it's a darned useful term. Another term is "Bowdlerization," which refers to the act of deleting obscene or forbidden material in text, and often has literary applications.

Comment: although demonization is not quite the same, Bowdlerization is definitely placed in the "future use" and "pull out at parties" pile

Comment: Whoever's dishing out the downvotes is cordially invited to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with *demonization*, as suggested by The Raven. Otherwise, a less marked word referring to the process could be ***proscription*** (from the meaning of *proscribe* that is synonymous to *condemn*).

Answer (score 0):

I found a German word, but it translates back to "to make taboo".  I see phrases of "becoming taboo", but no particular word.

Comment: Would you mind posting the words, "to make taboo" could work

Comment: "tabuisieren" is the German word.

Comment: Also see "to place under taboo."