# What is the meaning of the pejorative form of “gay”?

Tags: pejorative-language

Dictionaries don’t define the pejorative use of *gay*, but the term is used in common parlance. For example:

> That’s so gay.

or

> You’re gay.

Is there a way of establishing what *gay* means when used pejoratively?

Comment: The *slang* usage of *gay* is offensive/ pejorative. Otherwise in formal English, what is "pejorative" of **any** meaning of the word? **Neither** sense is pejorative.

Comment: This is like asking whether there’s any way of establishing what any other pejorative means that has appropriated from a group and used as a general put down, like the n-word and many others.

Comment: [Obviously related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/181959).  [This, too](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5610), and many more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Dictionaries don't define the pejorative use of gay

Some of them do:

- [Dictionary.com: Gay](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gay): "awkward, stupid, or bad; lame: *This game is really gay*.
- [Oxford Dictionaries: Gay](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gay): "Foolish, stupid, or unimpressive: *he thinks the obsession with celebrity is totally gay*."
- [Wiktionary: Gay (English)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gay#English): "Used to express dislike: lame, uncool, stupid: *This game is gay; let’s play a different one. = I dislike this game; let’s play a different one.*"

Answer (score 12):

Anecdotally, growing up in the nineteen-eighties and nineties (in England and then the US), I perceived "gay" as an insult growing in popularity directly alongside the widening awareness of the concept of "gay" as an identity.  I was acutely sensitive to the one due to my private identification with the other, and I am quite certain none of the kids I knew were using some hypothetical other tradition of the word.

They called things "gay" precisely because gay people were different and shameful, and because adults discouraged mention of the subject, putting the word into the category of "naughty" (and therefore enjoyable) words that covers sex, genitalia and bodily functions.  Using the word in this way reinforced the negative connotations attached to gay people, and continues to do so even as diverse sexual identities become gradually more accepted.

Looking for separate explanations of the derogatory and descriptive senses of the word is misdirected; the referent is the same, it's just that the derogatory uses are attempts to hang disapproving connotations upon it.

UPDATE: [here's a snapshot](http://yourfaceisanadvert.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/jeff-and-akbar3_0003.jpg) of the evolving popular meaning of "gay" in 1986.

Answer (score 4):

No, *gay* used pejoratively has no special meaning to distinguish it from any other slight meant to disparage and discredit those whom it refers to.  Their only real “meaning” is to be mean.  It’s just like calling something *lame*, which is casually insensitive to people who cannot walk or run easily.

In this way, this is just like any other slur based on race or national origin or religion or sex or disability physical or mental, or on anything else that the execrable dregs of humanity use against their fellow man.

I will not besmirch this site by enumerating a list of spiteful examples of these, but I’m sure countless many of the same bilious character come readily to mind once you try to think of some.

Such insults are nothing but base stigmatizations — rank put-downs, if you would — committed by xenophobic churls and others of equally low breeding, empathy, intellect, courtesy, and judgement.

Whether done in casual passing or as an active affront, every single one of these slurs is verbal violence but thinly veiled and summarily vile.  They can be used as hate speech — and often are.  Their intent is to dehumanize and sometimes even demonize those whom such speakers perceive to be “different” from themselves, and by extension inherently inferior from them.

That is their “meaning”.

Comment: Have you got a source for this?

Comment: @dwjohnston Cripples can be lame people, and lame people can be cripples. So as soon as *cripple* became a taboo word, *lame* took on the job and then soon enough expanded into a general-purpose put-down.  This is no different.

Comment: I suspect the OP does not mean any of this at all.

Comment: What do you mean _lame took on the job_? _Lame_ has always meant _cripple_, it might even predate _cripple_.

Comment: @Frank I meant that *lame* took on the job of a put-down used on anything. You call something “lame” that you don’t like.  It’s the same situation.

Comment: @tchrist: The term "crippled", applied to inanimate objects, has a semantic advantage over "lame" in that it generally functions more as a passive past participle than a descriptive adjective.  If something is "crippled", that often suggests that its a condition is a result of some identifiable action by someone.  By contrast, things which are "lame" are generally ineffective, but their ineffectiveness may not have any particular identifiable cause.

Comment: @tchrist When was _cripple_ used as a generic put-down for inanimate objects and was it a US thing? Was it used like _That movie was crippled_ or something similar? Obviously things can become crippled, a crippled ship, crippled machines and stuff but just generic put-downs? I'm sure that never made it to the UK (or any other country). I'm genuinely interested to hear the story behind crippled as a generic put-down, I've never heard it used in the same sense as say _wanker_. I've heard _this film is wank_, _that hat is completely wank_ etc, but never _crippled_.

Comment: +1 for the analogy with *lame*. IMHO, it is indeed the same phenomenon. And I tend to think that someone who cannot see this cannot see the forest for the trees (or for another reason).

Comment: @Drew Thanks. Your “or for another reason” is probably on the money: note the up/down-vote totals on this answer to see what I mean. This is almost certainly because people do not ever want to be told that they should avoid saying something they’re used to saying, where by *something* I mean anything at all, even when they are quite directly instructed that doing so hurts others. The constant retort of “Well, that’s their own dumb fault!” is a classic case of blaming the victim and letting the perpetrator smugly get away with whatever his preferred form of abuse is. Civil society says no.

Answer (score 2):

When used as a pejorative, it can mean either "stereotypically homosexual" or "derisable" - it depends on the context, and the intent of the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of this sense of the word *gay* is; undesirable, inferior or unwelcome in a way comparable to how homosexuals are undesirable, inferior or unwelcome.

It's certainly possible to use the word in that sense without actually considering gay people to be undesirable, inferior or unwelcome, and someone using the term in that way is not necessarily homophobic—I've even heard gay people use it that way—though I wouldn't recommend it to those who prefer to be careful in their use of language, either.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, I asked my kids after I heard them using it (about 10 years ago). They didn't really have a clear description except what I think is what used to be called "camp" behaviour. The origin may have been shows like Queer Eye for the Straight Guy in which camp and somewhat OCD behaviour were a running joke.

They certainly did NOT mean it as being a slur on gay people.

Comment: It has nothing to do with campness. It just means "bad", in the same way that "lame" just means bad and has nothing to do with physical disabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It usually doesn't mean anything except "gay" (homosexual), it just indicates that the person that uses the word believes this is a negative characteristic to hold.

Some sources do claim additional meanings however:

> Slang: Often Disparaging and Offensive. awkward, stupid, or bad; lame:
>
> **-**[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gay)

> a derogative slang expression with a general meaning "pathetic, inferor"
>
> **-**[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_%28disambiguation%29)

For more examples of this type of word, see also:

- [List of ethnic group names used as insults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_group_names_used_as_insults) on Wikipedia.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some kind of source material for this answer.

Comment: To clarify, in your first sentence you mean 'homosexual'?

Comment: @dwjohnston That's right, I'll edit that in for clarity.

Comment: I doubt that many people who use *gay* pejoratively actually dislike gay people.  It has simply gone the way of words like *lame* and *dumb*: yes, they can refer to disabilities, but few people calling something *lame* intend to demean cripples.

Comment: _Gay_ in the pejorative sense can be used about things that one would never realistically describe as homosexual. I've heard people use it about things like sodas (“Pepsi is so gay”) or policies (“Law enforcement cutbacks are so gay”). While I have heard some people humorously take this one step further and actually use _homosexual_ instead of _gay_ in this context, I've never heard anyone describing neither Pepsi nor police cutbacks as having actual homosexual tendencies.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'm not sure about police cutbacks, but products such as soft drinks may sometimes be called "gay" may sometimes if they have acquired a reputation as being more strongly favored by homosexual people than by heterosexual people, without any implication that the association between sexuality and product preference is anything more than coincidence (or, for that matter, superstition).

Answer (score -2):

On the assumption that *That's so gay* and *You're gay* are not meant to mean *That's so homosexual* and *You're homosexual* there is a good possibility that the modern term *gay* is an antiphrasis or semantic shift of an existing definition of gay.

The word *gay* has been around for more than 700 years, only in the last 100 or so has it taken on an extra meaning of *A [male] homosexual* and only in the last 50 years has that become a well known definition.

OED1 has a definition of *gay* as *Brilliantly good, excellent, fine*. This seems to be a perfect fit for the current use of *gay* when applied to inanimate objects to mean *not good, poor, rubbish* when negated. OED1 does note that the usage is obsolete, but that doesn't mean it can't be used.

This is the same as *bad* meaning *good*, *sick* meaning *excellent*, *wicked* meaning *wonderful*. These inversions appear to come mostly from skateboarding slang and it's no surprise to me to find that the OED2 state the first mention of *gay* meaning *Foolish, stupid, lame* comes from a skate boarding magazine from the late 1970's.

Given that, in general, homosexuality is more accepted now than it has been for many years and that *gay* is the terminology preferred by the homosexual community (LBGT, Gay Pride etc), I find it hard to believe that expressing the *gayness* of an inanimate object, or a person, can be related to the meaning of *gay* for *homosexual*.

Comment: I’m afraid you missed the point. They use *gay* as a “let’s call something a bad thing we don’t like” kind of put-down.  It’s one of those passive things, like getting *gypped* out of a good deal, or *jewed* down.  Are those acceptable? What about calling somebody the n-word just because we don’t like them, no matter the color of their skin?  It happens; what does it “mean”?

Comment: Except that "jewed" and "gypped" are drawn from stereotypes of groups based on an imputed group characteristic or attribute. As "gay" is used in the OP, it has much in common with your example of "lame" but not with "gypped".

Comment: @tchrist, `They use gay as a “let’s call something a bad thing we don’t like”` when you say `they` do you mean everyone, people you know or someone you know well, maybe you could provide a source for it? You'll need to ask a new question about the other terms, this questions is about _gay_.

Comment: I may be a little biased but this answer appears to be saying that, since it's possible to cook up a far-fetched explanation for the term, and there's no longer prejudice against gay people(!), it's unlikely that anyone who calls something "gay" is ever simply ascribing to it the negative connotations that being a homosexual person has.  It would be an understatement to say I don't agree with this.

Comment: @bobtato `and there's no longer prejudice against gay people(!),` it's not saying that at all but it is saying that using the word _gay_ to mean _Foolish, stupid, lame_ is not attempting to imply that a person being homosexual is a bad thing. That's why you don't hear anyone say _Man, that movie was so [insert any anti-gay term you wish]_. Any one wanting to use a word that implies _this is as 'bad' as homosexuality_ has a wide range of choices.

Comment: You do hear people using e.g. "queer" or "faggy" in a similar way, and you hear people saying "no homo", which has only taken off in the last couple of years.  The language both follows and precedes the prejudice-- some people use these words because they're bigots, but others acquire negative connotations of homosexuality by using these words.  Even if we _were_ talking about completely distinct homonyms (but we're not), knowing "gay" to mean feeble / effeminate / pathetic would make it harder to attach that word to your own identity.

Comment: Some things were _queer_ long before _queer_ was used to describe homosexual behaviour. What I'm saying is that the use of _gay_ as described above is just another meaning for the word, after all it's hard to see that five year old children, who might call their school satchel _gay_ have any idea of the history or current state of prejudice against homosexuals and certainly shouldn't be described, as one answer puts it, as _the execrable dregs of humanity_. Rather like your linked cartoon, it's not changing the meaning of the word, it's just adding another different meaning.

Comment: @Tchrist I've no idea what it looks like on your monitor but it's not bright neon on mine - it's rather a dull grey, however the color makes no difference to me so I have edited it to simple italics. Now enough with the _obnoxious, chest-beating, pharisaic_ nonsense.